# Replace text with content of a JavaScript property by name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
/\{([a-zA-Z\.]*)\
```

that I want to use to replace some text like this:

```
{identifier}
```

with value an object property with the name of the value of the brackets. In this case it would be `object.identifier`. Something like:

```
html.replace(/\{([a-zA-Z\.]*)\}/g, object.$1);
```

Thanks for the fast resonse here is the final code

```
html = html.replace(/\{([a-zA-Z\.]*)\}/g, $.proxy(function (match, contents, offset, s) {
    return objx.get(this.response[object.attr("data-index")],contents);
},this));
```

Comment: Further reading on replace function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: Thanks tried to find some articles about it, but only WC3 basic tutorial came up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a callback for `.replace`:

```
html.replace(/{([a-zA-Z.]*)}/g, function(x, a) {
    return object[a];
});
```